# Repeated Character Whose First Appearance in Python

Tags: python, character

You are given a string S
Your task is to find the first occurrence of an alphanumeric character in S(read from left to right) that has consecutive repetitions.

Input Format
A single line of input containing the string S.

Output Format
Print the first occurrence of the repeating character. If there are no repeating characters, print -1.

For example,
If I input the below string

```
..12345678910111213141516171820212223
```

the result is

```
1
```

I solved this problem but that's not correct.
My code is

```
def firstRepeatedChar(str):   
   h = {}
   for ch in str: 
      if ch in h: 
         return ch;         
      else: 
         h[ch] = 0

   return -1
n = input()
print(firstRepeatedChar(n))
```

but if I input the ^^cmmit^^, the result is not correct.
How can I solve this problem with python? Please help me.

Comment: unable to reproduce https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/FancyYellowgreenInstitute

Comment: Can you give an example of input/expected output/actual output?

Comment: @JoranBeasley `^` is incorrect. It's supposed to return the `first occurrence of an *alphanumeric* character` that's consecutively repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pythonic way to do something like this is to use `zip()` to make consecutive pairs of tuples (like `(1, 2), (2, 3) ...` and then just return the first one where both are equal and alphanumeric.

`next()` takes an optional parameter for what to return when there's nothing left, to which here you can pass `-1`. [`isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) can be used to test is a string is alphanumeric:

```
def firstRepeatedChar(s):
    return next((j for j, i in zip(s, s[1:]) if j == i and j.isalnum()), -1)

firstRepeatedChar("..12345678910111213141516171820212223")
# 1
firstRepeatedChar("^^cmmit^^")
# 'm'
firstRepeatedChar("^^cmit^^")
# -1
```

Comment: Sorry. My account had some issues.